# Why would sTimebaseInfo.denom be 0?

Tags: c++, ios, timing

I'm using this bit of boilerplate to test performance of some video settings on iOS 5.1.1 (4s):

```
static mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebaseInfo = { 0, 0 };
if ( sTimebaseInfo.denom == 0 ) {
    kern_return_t err = mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"unable to get mach timebase info: %d",err);
    }
}
uint64_t        start = mach_absolute_time();
uint64_t        end;
uint64_t        elapsed;
uint64_t        elapsedNano;

    // stuff

end = mach_absolute_time();
// Calculate the duration.
elapsed = end - start;
elapsedNano = elapsed * sTimebaseInfo.numer;
elapsedNano /= sTimebaseInfo.denom;
```

But sTimebaseInfo.denom is always 0, even after mach_timebase_info is run. It gives no error. I don't know what to do with that. :) It's not *imperative* to get the values in nanoseconds; I can compare results without, obviously. But it sure would be nice.

Help? :)

Comment: That shouldn't happen, and I've certainly never seen it happen. I copied-and-pasted this code into a new project and it worked correctly in both the simulator and device. Did you #import <mach/mach_time.h>? Can you post a self-contained project that others can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: That's good to hear. It's looking like an issue with doing it inside - (void)captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer: fromConnection:... outside of that I get a normal value (125 numerator, 3 denominator). Thanks :)

Comment: Weird! Only thing I can imagine is that something is out-of-the-ordinary about the thread or dispatch queue that `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` calls you on. Unfortunately the iOS kernel isn't open-source, so we can't see the source to `mach_timebase_info` like we can on OS X.